# Orientation of eNode antennas

Tags: antenna, network, cellular

What type of omni-directional antennas is used at an LTE base station, also known as eNode? and What is the orientation of such antennas? and how come the 3GPP path-loss model for such antennas is independent of orientation? (The path-loss model is: \$128+37.6\log_{10}(d/1000)\$ where \$d\$ is the distance from antenna in meters.)

Comment: Please provide links to the device in question and the path loss model.

Comment: I just added the path-loss model eqn. to my question. I do not know what antennas they used in LTE networks, hence, the question.